# Subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ that is not a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I just had a test, and one of the questions was to show that there is at least one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ that is not a subring.

I couldn't think of one and still can't, so I cheated and said $\{ (2k,2k) \colon  \ k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is a subgroup but not a (unitary) subring... In this class we don't require a ring to have identity so it is wrong obviously.

Anyways can you please give me an example?

Thank you

Comment: Just look at a few more subgroups. It shouldn't take you long to find a counterexample.

Comment: You can use `\oplus` instead of `\bigoplus`, which you might prefer to save for things like $\bigoplus\limits_{p\text{ prime }}\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, say.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thank you, I'll use that from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Observe that $(1,2)·(1,2) = (1,4)$.

Comment: I think I get it, we can consider the subgroup $(\mathbb{Z}_3 \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_3,+)$ where $(a,b)+(a'b')=(a+a',b+b')$ '+' being the regular sum in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and the product such that $(a,b) \dot (a',b')=(aa',bb')$ and $aa'$ is the regular product in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_3$, by which I assume you mean $\mathbb Z/3$, is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_3$ i mean $\{ 0,1,2\}$ where 1+2=0 and 2+2=1

Is that the same as $\mathbb{Z}/3$? If so, why is not a subgroup? It is a subset of $Z$, and it is a group (it has identity $0$, it is associative, and every element has an inverse)

Comment: @Orlando No. This, as Jim said, is not a subgroup of $ℤ$ or $ℤ × ℤ$. Instead consider $ℤ(1,2) = \{ (x,2x);\, x ∈ ℤ\}$ or what AndreasCaranti suggested. Check if they’re subgroups and whether they are multiplicatively closed or not.

Comment: @K.Stm., thanks for the quote. Your example is fine, +1.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being annoying but why isn't $\mathbb{Z}/3$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$? Is it because the operation isn't the same?

Also, I can easily check $\mathbb{Z} (1,2)$ is a subgroup, but isn't it also closed under multiplication, making it a subring of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

Given $(x_1,2x_1),(x_2,2x_2) \in \mathbb{Z} (1,2)$, we have $(x_1,2x_1)(x_2,2x_2)=(x_1x_2,2(2x_1x_2))$

Comment: @Orlando, subgroup means indeed same operation. Also note that $(x_1x_2, 2 (2x_1x_2))$ is not of the form $(x, 2x)$. i.e. *second coordinate is twice the first one*.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Oh right, of course.. I can't believe I didn't see that. oh well I guess I should get some sleep xD

Comment: First of all: $2(2x₁x₂) ≠ 2(x₁x₂)$ which was the requirement of being in that subgroup. (Put $x=x₁x₂$.) More concretely: $(1,2) ∈ ℤ(1,2)$ but $(1,2)·(1,2) = (1,4) \notin ℤ(1,2)$. Next, a subgroup $S$ of a bigger group $G$ must be a *part* of the bigger group in the sense that you need to have a structure preserving inclusion $S → G$. But since $1+1+1 = 0$ in $ℤ/3$ while  $1+1+1 ≠ 0$ in $ℤ$, no such inclusion $ℤ/3 → ℤ$ exists.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** Consider the subgroup $\{ (x, -x) : x \in \Bbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @Orlando, you're welcome!